# Creating a control to automatically encode data

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a custom control i.e.(textbox) that I want to make sure the data is encoded to the page when it displays.  is there a way to do this?

Comment: You're going to have to be much more clear what you mean by this. (examples?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe textboxes are encoded by default, but something like below could help you out with other controls.

```
txtBox.Text = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(stringToEncode)
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for.  Sorry for the minimal information.